# Is there a way to apply custom shaders to macOS screen?

Tags: desktop, macos

I know macOS has a feature to invert the screen using Control+Option+Command+8.

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way, like a macOS feature, an application, or even some API to apply other effects to the whole screen?

Comment: which OS do you have

Comment: I am on Mojave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In High Sierra you can use keyboard shortcut to Invert Colors

Option+Command+I

More screen options are in System preference > Accessibility > Display

[image]